# Python email quoted-printable encoding problem

Tags: python, email, encoding, imaplib

I am extracting emails from Gmail using the following:

```
def getMsgs():
 try:
    conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
  except:
    print 'Failed to connect'
    print 'Is your internet connection working?'
    sys.exit()
  try:
    conn.login(username, password)
  except:
    print 'Failed to login'
    print 'Is the username and password correct?'
    sys.exit()

  conn.select('Inbox')
  # typ, data = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN SUBJECT "%s")' % subject)
  typ, data = conn.search(None, '(SUBJECT "%s")' % subject)
  for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
    yield walkMsg(msg)

def walkMsg(msg):
  for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() != "text/plain":
      continue
    return part.get_payload()
```

However, some emails I get are nigh impossible for me to extract dates (using regex) from as encoding-related chars such as '=', randomly land in the middle of various text fields. Here's an example where it occurs in a date range I want to extract:

> Name:  KIRSTI   Email: 
>   kirsti@blah.blah   Phone #:  + 999
>   99995192   Total in party:  4 total, 0
>   children   Arrival/Departure:  Oct 9=
>   ,
>   2010 - Oct 13, 2010 - Oct 13, 2010

Is there a way to remove these encoding characters?

Comment: Yeah... I thought it put those where there's a line break to wrap lines. Should be a lib to decode it properly.

Comment: Try https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could/should use the [`email.parser`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.FeedParser) module to decode mail messages, for example (quick and dirty example!):

```
from email.parser import FeedParser
f = FeedParser()
f.feed("<insert mail message here, including all headers>")
rootMessage = f.close()

# Now you can access the message and its submessages (if it's multipart)
print rootMessage.is_multipart()

# Or check for errors
print rootMessage.defects

# If it's a multipart message, you can get the first submessage and then its payload
# (i.e. content) like so:
rootMessage.get_payload(0).get_payload(decode=True)
```

Using the "decode" parameter of [`Message.get_payload`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload), the module automatically decodes the content, depending on its encoding (e.g. quoted printables as in your question).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Python3.6 or later, you can use the [`email.message.Message.get_content()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content) method to decode the text automatically.  This method supersedes `get_payload()`, though `get_payload()` is still available.

Say you have a string `s` containing this email message (based on the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.examples.html#email-examples) in the docs):

```
Subject: Ayons asperges pour le =?utf-8?q?d=C3=A9jeuner?=
From: =?utf-8?q?Pep=C3=A9?= Le Pew <pepe@example.com>
To: Penelope Pussycat <penelope@example.com>,
 Fabrette Pussycat <fabrette@example.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

    Salut!

    Cela ressemble =C3=A0 un excellent recipie[1] d=C3=A9jeuner.

    [1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

    --Pep=C3=A9
   =20
```

Non-ascii characters in the string have been encoded with the `quoted-printable` encoding, as specified in the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

Create an email object:

```
import email
from email import policy

msg = email.message_from_string(s, policy=policy.default)
```

Setting the policy is required here; otherwise [`policy.compat32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.Compat32) is used, which returns a legacy Message instance that doesn't have the get_content method.  [`policy.default`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.default) will eventually become the default policy, but as of Python3.7 it's still `policy.compat32`.

The `get_content()` method handles decoding automatically:

```
print(msg.get_content())

Salut!

Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

[1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

--Pepé
```

If you have a multipart message, `get_content()` needs to be called on the individual parts, like this:

```
for part in message.iter_parts():
    print(part.get_content())
```

Comment: You can use it even with `message_from_bytes`:
`email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=email.policy.default)`
helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That's known as quoted-printable encoding. You probably want to use something like `quopri.decodestring` - http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html