# Python imaplib: Display non-ASCII characters correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, email, non-ascii-characters

I am using Python 3.5 and `imaplib` to fetch an e-mail from GMail and print its body. The body contains non-ASCII characters.
These are 'encoded' in a strange way and I cannot find out how to fix this.

```
import email
import imaplib

c = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
c.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')

c.select('Inbox')
_, data = c.fetch(b'12345', '(RFC822)')

mail = data[0][1]
message = email.message_from_bytes(mail)
payload = message.get_payload()

body = mail[0].as_string()
print(body)
```

Gives

```
>> ... Mit freundlichen Gr=C3=BC=C3=9Fen ...
```

instead of the desired

```
>> ... Mit freundlichen Grüßen ...
```

It looks to me like this is not an issue of encoding but one of conversion. But how do I tell Python to convert the characters correctly? Is there a more convenient library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python email encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040074/python-email-encoding-problem)

Comment: If you're using python3.6 or later you can use `EmailMessage.get_content()` to decode quoted-printable text automatically.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895660/5320906) to the duplicate target question.

Answer (score 6):

The text is encoded with [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), which is a way to encode non-ascii characters in ascii text.  You can decode it using python's [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/quopri.html#module-quopri) module.

```
>>> import quopri
>>> bs = b'Gr=C3=BC=C3=9Fen'

>>> # Decode quoted-printable to raw bytes.
>>> utf8 = quopri.decodestring(bs)

>>> # Decode bytes to text.
>>> s = utf8.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(s)
Grüßen
```

You may find that `quoted-printable` is the value of the email's `content-transfer-encoding` header.

Comment: Python should already be decoding this when you get the payload, though. Perhaps it was double-encoded by the sender?

Comment: Adding a sample of the message (ideally, reduced to just a few lines, enough to see the essential headers and a line of encoded text) would help us conclusively debug this.

Comment: @tripleee in 3.6+ EmailMessage.get_content() will decode quoted-printable automatically - I added an answer to your dupe target.