# Parsing raw email with python email library adding unwanted characters

Tags: python, email, parsing

I am using python standard email parsing library to parse the raw email that I am getting from amazon ses mail service.

Below is my code for the same.

```
import json
import email
from email.Utils import parseaddr

def parse(raw_email):
    message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    text_plain = None
    text_html = None

    for part in message.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain' and text_plain is None:
            text_plain = part.get_payload()
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html' and text_html is None:
            text_html = part.get_payload()

    parsed_email_object = {
      'to': parseaddr(message.get('To'))[1],
      'from': parseaddr(message.get('From'))[1],
      'delivered to': parseaddr(message.get('Delivered-To'))[1],
      'subject': message.get('Subject'),
      'text_plain': text_plain,
      'text_html': text_html,
    }

    json_string = json.dumps(parsed_email_object)
    return json_string
```

when I am parsing my raw email, it is not parsing 100%, it is giving me unwanted characters like this

```
this is a replyo from the gmail indbo asdf asdf asdfa sdfa=
sd sdfa sdfa fasd
=C2=A0dfa sf asdf
a sdfas
<= div>f asdf=C2=A0


Is there anything else like some decoding option to parse it correctly.
```

Comment: did you try the encoding/decoding fix `part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(part.get_content_charset())`

Comment: no I haven't done that, just let me try.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895660/5320906

Comment: @Ja8zyjits thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment as an answer so that it gets noticed.

```
part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(part.get_content_charset())
```

This will solve the issue of encoding