# Python is unable to read response properly from few email domains such as hotmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am having some issue while reading email from outlook using Python.  Somehow the content gets either encrypted or converted in byte code in original email; however if same email get read using gmail the response shows up as normal text.

Unfortunately I can't share the email however here is what I am using maybe it helps you to point me to right direction.

I am trying to read my gmail accounts email responses.  For that I am using:
imapclient and email.parser packages from python.
my imports:

```
import pyzmail
from imapclient import IMAPClient
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from email.parser import Parser
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import decode_header
```

Using following code I am successfully able to parse the email sucha as From, Response Date, Subject and body.

```
parser = Parser()
emailMsg = parser.parsestr(msg)
pdict = {}
pdict['From'] = emailMsg.get('From').strip()
pdict['ResponseDate'] = emailMsg.get('Date').strip()
#pdict['To'] = emailMsg.get('To').strip()
logging.info("Email Send From: "+pdict['From'])
pdict['Subject']= parseSubject(emailMsg.get('Subject').strip())
if emailMsg.is_multipart():
    pdict['Response'] = getMultiPartResponse(emailMsg.get_payload()[0].as_string())
else:
    pdict['Response'] = getSinglePartResponse(emailMsg.get_payload())
return(pdict)
```

Doing this I am able to parse most of the response however I notice that if end user is using microsoft email especially hotmail; the email's original message gets encrypted or converted in bytecode.  Therefore python email parser returns some encrypted string.  However on Gmail client these messages read as normal message.

For example I am reading response on gmail as:

```
Thank You.
```

But Python code is parsing as:

```
WUVTDQoNCj4gT24gRGVjIDE2LCAyMDIwLCBhdCAxMjo1MyBQTSwgSGVhbGluZyBUb3VjaCBSZWhh YmlsaXRhdGlvbiBDZW50cmUgPGluZm8uaHRyY0BnbWFpbC5jb20+IHdyb3RlOg0KPiANCj4g77u/
```

Has anyone else come across this issue?

So far I am only noticing these issues from hotmail domain emails all other domains python program is able to read the message successfully.

I am not sure if hotmail uses some especial encryption which needs to be take care at code level to convert response to normal text.  All other attributes of email gets read correctly except email body.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The string

"WUVTDQoNCj4gT24gRGVjIDE2LCAyMDIwLCBhdCAxMjo1MyBQTSwgSGVhbGluZyBUb3VjaCBSZWhh YmlsaXRhdGlvbiBDZW50cmUgPGluZm8uaHRyY0BnbWFpbC5jb20+IHdyb3RlOg0KPiANCj4g77u/"

is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded data.  Messages may be encoded like this to enable non-ASCII text to be handled by servers that can only process ASCII text.  It can be decoded using the tools in the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module in the standard library, like this:

```py
import base64
s = base64.b64decode('WUVTDQoNCj4gT24gRGVjIDE2LCAyMDIwLCBhdCAxMjo1MyBQTSwgSGVhbGluZyBUb3VjaCBSZWhh YmlsaXRhdGlvbiBDZW50cmUgPGluZm8uaHRyY0BnbWFpbC5jb20+IHdyb3RlOg0KPiANCj4g77u/')
```

The result is a bytes instance

```py
b'YES\r\n\r\n> On Dec 16, 2020, at 12:53 PM, Healing Touch Rehabilitation Centre <info.htrc@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n> \r\n> \xef\xbb\xbf
```

If the content transfer encoding header has been correctly set on the email, calling

```
emailMsg.get_payload(decode=True)
```

should perform the decoding, if `emailMsg.is_multipart()` is `False`.  If `emailMsg.is_multipart()` is `True` then you would need to call `get_payload` on each of the parts.

The [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) class provided with the "new" email API (Python 3.6+) provides a [get_content](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content) method which will automatically decode (assuming the correct headers are in place) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895660/5320906) for an example.