# IMAP4: How to correctly decode UTF-8 encoded message body?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, imaplib

When fetching a UTF-8 encoded email with the code below, the message gets messed up when I try to programmatically access the email content. Here is what I do:

```py
import email
import imaplib

# Login and search a list of emails
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=HOST_ADDRESS,
                      port=HOST_PORT)
M.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASS)
M.select(readonly=True)
_, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
msgnums = data[0].split()

# Fetch emails one by one
for i, num in enumerate(msgnums): 
    # Also tried '(UID BODY[TEXT])' instead of '(RFC822)'...
    _, content = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')

    # For the text parts, it holds:
    #   Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
    #   Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

    # Save email to file
    with open("test.eml", "bw") as fid:
        fid.write(content[0][1])
```

For simplicity, I illustrate the problem for the word "München" with non-ASCII letter ü, which occurs in my e-mails.

When the file test.eml is opened in an email client (e.g., Apple Mail), the word `München` is displayed correctly. When the file is opened in a text editor, the word appears as `M=C3=BCnchen`. This makes sense, because the following applies:

```py
s = "München"
print(s.encode("utf-8"))
# b'M\xc3\xbcnchen'
```

**The problem:** How can I decode the body of the email correctly, so that "München" is represented correctly also within my code? No matter what I have tried, the escape character `\x` is always replaced by `=`, as is already the case with the test.eml.

Here is what I have tried so far to decode the message:

```py
print(type(content[0][1]))
# Console: <class 'bytes'>
print(content[0][1].decode("utf-8"))
# Console: M=C3=BCnchen

# Convert to EmailMessage
msg = email.message_from_bytes(content[0][1])

for part in msg.walk():
    print(type(part))
    # Console: <class 'email.message.Message'>
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/html":
        print(part)
        # Console: M=C3=BCnchen
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        print(part)
        # Console: M=C3=BCnchen

# Enforce UTF8 when reading message from bytes:
from email.policy import EmailPolicy
policy = EmailPolicy(utf8=True)
msg = email.message_from_bytes(content[0][1], policy=policy)

for part in msg.walk():
    # ...
    # Same as above:
    # Console: M=C3=BCnchen
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here? Why does imaplib.IMAP4 represent the UTF-8 escape character `\x` as `=`? And how to fix this?

Comment: `import quopri; quopri.decodestring( b'M=C3=BCnchen').decode()` returns `'München'`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable and vice versa: `quopri.encodestring( 'München'.encode())` returns `b'M=C3=BCnchen'`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895660/5320906) may help.

Comment: @snakecharmerb This solved my problem. Thank you!