# Encoding types and using encode() and decode() in python

Tags: python, decode, encode, translate

So I created a little hobby project of a small service where I can email a server with a foreign language, and it will send me a reply of the translation.

Long story short, emails/MIME want to be helpful and convert the foreign text to a more relevant charset.

So they convert something like: `это тестовая текстовая строка`
To something like: `=DC=D4=CF =D4=C5=D3=D4=CF=D7=C1=D1 =D3=D4=D2=CF=CB=C1 =D4=C5=CB=D3=D4=C1`

They do tell you the charset, when they convert it (e.g. this was koi8-r), but how can I use this to convert it to a more 'friendly' encoding, that my translation server can use (argostranslate).

My thought process was to do something like:

```
dataOut = dataIn.encode(charset).decode('utf-8')
```

but trying to decode it or encode it to anything just leaves it in the `=XX=XX=XX...` format.

I am assuming I am being stupid in some way, but if someone knows how to solve this, that would be great.
The key thing is that my method needs to accept essentially any type of incoming charset that MIME decides to throw at me.

Comment: What you're looking at is [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, which is very specific to how emails are encoded. You need to decode/parse your emails with proper email parsers. This has little to do with character encodings per se.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/quopri.html : `quopri.decodestring( dataIn).decode( 'koi8-r')` returns `'это тестовая строка текста'`… BTW, switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: thank you both of you!!!
based on what deceze said, i actually found that quopri and got it working!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4040074/5320906)